# Alamofire 5 with self-signed certificate

Tags: alamofire

I'd like to bypass certificate validation using **Alamofire 5** and Swift 4. I'm using Alamofire to connect to a server with a self-signed certificate. This is similar to this question [Alamofire with a self-signed certificate / ServerTrustPolicy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553414/alamofire-with-a-self-signed-certificate-servertrustpolicy), but the answers are for previous Alamofire versions and it's not clear to me how to apply this approach to version 5. Does anyone know how to implement this in Alamofire 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's very similar in Alamofire 5 but `ServerTrustPolicy` has been refactored into a protocol with conforming types for better extensibility. Similar to the answer you linked, you'll need to create a `ServerTrustManager` for your domain:

```
let manager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: ["your.domain.here": DisabledTrustEvaluator()])
let session = Session(serverTrustManager: manager)
```

Of course, you'll still need to add ATS exceptions for your domains as well.

Additionally, you should never ship code that uses the `DisabledTrustEvaluator`, as it would allow all invalid TLS connections.

Comment: How would you do this in a permanent way without trust disabled making ios networking evaluate the self signed certificate and the key? I have a bountied question here to capture your fancy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63846061/ios-alamofire-certificate-pinning-with-a-private-key

Comment: DisabledEvaluator has been deprecated, the new name is DisabledTrustEvaluator